# SQL binding mechanisms should be used

Tags: java, sonarqube, sql-injection

I have a code as following :

```
final String query = "SELECT id FROM " + getSimpleName() + " WHERE " + relationName + ".id = :successor";
final Query queryConcerned = this.entityManager.createQuery(query);
query.setParameter("successor", successorId);
```

But Sonar gives the following warning :

> Use a variable binding mechanism to construct this query instead of
>   concatenation.

As you can see the values I'm concatenating are not parameters, in doing so, am I vulnerable to SQL injections, if so, how can I solve this ?

Comment: The fix for this is to simply not concatenate your query together, but to use a single string instead.  As to _how_ you do this, you'll need to find a way to not have this need.  If you need to support say 3 tables, then create 3 statements, one for each table, each using a single string (of course, you have another concatenation in there, but hopefully you get the point).

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen yes I got your point, the problem is this code is generic and the tables to support are unknown, unfortunately building a string for each case is not possible atm.

Comment: Then ignore those warnings, there is no reason why this should stop your code from _compiling_.  Anyway, the warnings are just saying that you _might_ get injected.  If you strictly control those table names internally, with zero input from the outside, it shouldn't be too dangerous.